# How to call get API request for search swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I trying to implement search box for searching the different product. For each character entered in search box, result should be refreshed. I already have a API to get list of product types. sample response type from the API.

But I don't know How do I call the search api using URLSession and result to be showed in the tableview and for each character entered in search box, result should be refreshed.

```
https:"YOUR URL"/?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=<b>\(txtFldSearch.text!)</b>&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like
```

but it didn't give any response.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can not do that in a reasonable way, performance will be really bad and since the calls are asynchronous you might get the answers back in another order than reqeusted .

Comment: @ Joakim Danielson  - Then how should I do that?is there any way?

Comment: Download data first and then filter against a local array and if it is to much data for a local array then you need to re-think your solution